# Unable to stream videos from vimeo on WebView

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-webview

I'm developing an app which requires streaming of videos uploaded in vimeo site. When I'm launching the webview from one of my activity, the vimeo site loads successfully onto the webview, but the problem starts here. When I click on the play icon, it doesn't move further. The loaded vimeo video page doens't play the video.

I tried to check whether it is the problem with Android itself, but proved wrong. If I individually copy the URL to Android browser and play, it plays successfully. This is where I'm going clueless, whether I'm missing on anything in the configured WebView.

My code here:

```
private void getWebPage(final String webpage, final String param2, String param3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final FrameLayout.LayoutParams ZOOM_PARAMS =
            new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            Gravity.BOTTOM);
            final Activity activity = this;
            getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS, Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
             mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);


            mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

             activity.setTitle(" Loading the content for... "+param2);  
             activity.setProgress(progress * 100);//Make the bar disappear after URL is loaded

          // Return the app name after finish loading
             if(progress == 100)
                // activity.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                 activity.setTitle("You are now viewing "+param2);

           }
         });

         mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
         mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
         mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
         mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
         mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
         mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

      FrameLayout mContentView = (FrameLayout) getWindow().
      getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);

      mWebView.loadUrl(webpage);
    //Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("http://vimeo.com/m/45057923"));
    /*Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse(webpage));
    startActivity(newIntent);*/

}
```

Answer (score -1):

It works with

```
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Yes, it didn't..and it's deprecated. Please see the newer syntax  mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);